# Clientside browser error when I open materialui.com website?

Tags: material-ui, microsoft-edge

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this or if it belongs in another stackoverflow property.  Unfortunately, materialui doesn't seem to have direct support other than paid so I'm not sure how else to possibly engage them on the issue.

I have been working on a development task using materialui and using their web page, such as https://mui.com/material-ui/react-paper/, for help.  Using Microsoft Edge as my default browser, their pages have opened as expected basically for years but especially as I have been working this project heavily for the past two weeks.

Suddenly, last night, whenever I open any page from their site, the page loads and displays properly for a split second and then the page goes blank except for this error message in the center of the screen:

> Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

Screenshot of all of the content of the browser console is below.

[image]

This happens for any page of their documentation as soon as I click the getting-started page.  I had existing tabs open for a few specific documentation pages and those also exhibit the same problem on refresh or reload.  Their product pages from home page to product description work.

The pages should open and display the documentation.  I have tried new browser windows in Edge and get the same problem.  New tabs in the original window all get the same problem. I have rebooted and still get the same problem.

Interestingly, if I open a private window in Edge, that works and Chrome works so it is still something related to my original opened windows.  I am hesitant about clearing cache and cookies; restoring all the cookie settings for all the sites I visit can be a real pain.

Even though the error says the problem is in the browser, and even though a private Edge browser works, I still think the problem is related to Material UI's website.  I suspect it's a problem with the code of an advertisement - I've certainly run into that in other sites in the past.

Using Chrome is obviously an option but I use Edge as my browser and don't want to have to use Chrome for one website; I'd like to find a way to resolve this if possible.

Answer (score 1):

> I am hesitant about clearing cache and cookies; restoring all the cookie settings for all the sites I visit can be a real pain.

You can choose to clear the page cache for an individual site that is having problems, navigating to `edge://settings/siteData` to find it. Somethint like this: [image]

In addition,try to disable the current extensions to check if that works.